# How to get grid background color for web-page?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

I want to have a grid like background color for the header section like in this website: http://www.grantstreetstation.com/

Here is the link of the image showing the color: [Link of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx9yi.jpg)

Comment: background color or background image?

Comment: [Create your own on the web](http://www.stripegenerator.com/).

Answer (score 1):

That is not a color but an background image. Use the [Google Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to inspect the CSS. There you will find this:

```
body {
  background: #f6f2e6 url(imgs/bg.png) left top repeat;
}
```

This is the image that will be repeated to create this structure:

http://www.grantstreetstation.com/imgs/bg.png

Answer (score 0):

Background of this website is a small image who repeats itself.

Image link is [IMAGE](http://www.grantstreetstation.com/imgs/bgHeader.png)

if you mean the **color** it is: `#EAE5D2`
and the stripes are : `#DED9C6`